# ibuffer - execute function on buffer at point

Tags: ibuffer

In the depth of the internet I found this function which I need foremost but you could see it as an example for any function that can be applied on a buffer.

```el
(defun open-in-desktop ()
  "Open the containing directory of the current file in desktop. Works in Microsoft Windows and Mac OS X."
  (interactive)
  (cond
   ((string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
    (w32-shell-execute "explore" (replace-regexp-in-string "/" "\\" default-directory t t)))
   ((string-equal system-type "darwin") (shell-command "open ."))))
```

Now I use `ibuffer` and I would like to execute that function on the buffer where the cursor is currently located (using a keybinding).

Currently I mark the buffer (<kbd>m</kbd>),execute `ibuffer-do-eval` (<kbd>E</kbd>) and then type (`open-in-desktop`). This works but is quite tedious.

I have no coding skills therefore, I would appreciate any help on that.

Comment: That function's documentation string string says it opens the current *file*, but it actually opens the current *directory*.

Comment: Omar, I have neither written the function, nor its description. I have edited the description a bit I hope its now nearer to the truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the example of `ibuffer-do-eval`:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "ibuffer"
  ;; M-x ibuffer-do-open-in-desktop
  (define-ibuffer-op open-in-desktop ()
    "Call `open-in-desktop' on current or marked buffers."
    (:opstring "opened"
     :modifier-p :maybe)
    (open-in-desktop))

  (define-key ibuffer-mode-map (kbd "C-c o") 'ibuffer-do-open-in-desktop))
```

---

*Edit:*

> Is there any way to remove the marking directly in that function without pressing <kbd>u</kbd>?

I don't think `define-ibuffer-op` facilitates that; but we could instead do something like:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "ibuffer"
  ;; M-x ibuffer-do-open-in-desktop
  (define-ibuffer-op open-in-desktop ()
    "Call `open-in-desktop' on current or marked buffers."
    (:opstring "opened"
     :modifier-p :maybe)
    (open-in-desktop))

  (defun my-ibuffer-open-in-desktop ()
    "Call `open-in-desktop' on current or marked buffers."
    (interactive)
    (if (ibuffer-marked-buffer-names)
        (ibuffer-do-open-in-desktop)
      (with-current-buffer (ibuffer-current-buffer :must-be-live)
        (open-in-desktop))))

  (define-key ibuffer-mode-map (kbd "C-c o") 'my-ibuffer-open-in-desktop))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I can definitivly go from here, there is just some minor caviat. When I hit "C-c o" the buffer is left marked. Is there any way to remove the marking directly in that function without pressing u?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to *unmark* the marked buffers, as we can't differentiate between a pre-marked buffer and a buffer which was marked by our command; however we can work around that by preventing an unmarked buffer from being marked on this account in the first place. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Obviously I haven't thought this far. Thanks for pointing that out and writing this extensive solution.